# Tracking website conversions from our backend

Tags: google-ads-api, google-analytics-4

I am using Firebase Analytics (which is built on top of GA4 from what I understood), along with Google Ads.

I have set up some events in GA4 as conversions, for example when a user signup, then I use these conversions to optimize my Google Ads campaign. This works well!

I now want to track not only signups, but also purchases. I could track them from the frontend, but it sounds dodgy to do that on the client side: what if the user blocks GA? what if a user maliciously triggers the event multiple times to mess with my campaign?

So instead I want to log the purchase events from the backend. However, it's very important that they're still properly tied to the originating ad click, so that Google Ads can properly optimize my campaign.

I am looking for some ID that I could send from my frontend to my backend to identify the user (and therefore the ad click). But I can't seem to find anything. What am I missing?